# Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices connection issue with Huawei Phone

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, huawei-mobile-services

We have one application which does communication with hardware devices like activity tracker using Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) technology.

The communication is working with all the phones which supports BLE but when we try to connect the tracker with Huawei phones, it simply do not work.

The flow is as below:

- App search for the activity tracker
- When app finds the tracker, it calls connect method of Bluetooth Gatt service.
- The tracker should be connected successfully and it should give response in "OnConnectionStateChanged()" method with status 0 and state 2 (success)
  . But the problem is, it is not connecting with the tracker successfully. When app initiate the connection call, it immediately gives disconnect callback with status 133 (Bluetooth Gatt failure).

Below are the logs which shows the issue:

```
I/Bluetooth: BtGatt.GattService:onConnected() - clientIf=6, connId=0, address=E6:4F:92:69:B7:95
I/Bluetooth: BluetoothProfileService:isAvailable(), mStartError=false, mCleaningUp=false
BluetoothGatt Check Status and NewState: 133|0
I/Bluetooth: BtGatt.GattService:clientDisconnect() - address=E6:4F:92:69:B7:95, connId=null
```

We also tested with "nRF Connect" application and in this application too, it gives disconnect callback with status 133 (Bluetooth Gatt failure). Please find the attached screenshot for the same.

[image]

If anyone came across the same situation, can you please help us?

Comment: Exactly which phone models have you tested that don't work? Have you tried reboot the phone?

Comment: We are using Huawei P8 lite device. We tried rebooting the phone but it didn't work.

Comment: Seeing the same here. Sometimes our BLE devices do not even show up during BLE scanning. Would be great if somebody has an idea of what can be done from a app developers side.

Answer (score 0):

Huawei phones are notorious of their bluetooth bug with BLE devices. Garmin, FitBit and Nokia/Withings activity trackers suffer from the same issue. Garmin developers have managed to somehow workaround this Huawei bug with a help of Huawei engineers.
https://support.garmin.com/en-US/?faq=3qBFoCgeH428IUUfc0SpZ7

Fitbit and Withings engineers haven't got around to talk to Huawei to solve the issue. It seems that something needs to be done differently in a client side (some timeout tweaks during BT handshaking? Ignoring error messages?)

Especially P8Lite, P9Lite and P10Lite are suffering from this issue in Android 6.x and 7.x versions. Could be that Huawei has screwed up something in those Android versions.

Comment: Where did you get the info, that Garmin had help from Huawai? Or do you by any chance have an idea / contact on where to start tackling that, besides the general huawai support. Any help is appreciated.